# Who was messaged in the post-credits scene of Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, credits

In *Avengers: Infinity War* post-credit scene, who did Nick Fury message?

> Was it Captain Marvel?

Comment: Answered on SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186339/what-is-the-symbol-in-the-infinity-war-post-credits-scene

Answer (score 28):

Yes, that was the Captain Marvel logo:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aww no, they could have done better. Bad hair, cheap zipper jacket. Not at all a superhero material , definitely not Thanos defeating like.

Comment: @paul New footage looks much better.

Comment: Looks way better now